# How does Breadth First Search work if the Queue is already empty after the 1st source node is dequeued?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, queue, breadth-first-search

According to Wikipedia, when using Breadth-First Search, you have to dequeue the node so that you can visit all the children (or neighbors of that particular node). This makes complete sense to me:

```
Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):

create empty set S
create empty queue Q      

add root to S
Q.enqueue(root)                      

while Q is not empty:
    current = Q.dequeue()
    if current is the goal:
        return current
    for each node n that is adjacent to current:
        if n is not in S:
            add n to S
            n.parent = current
            Q.enqueue(n)
```

However, the problem I have is that, if you just started with your first parent node, and you already dequeue to read the children node, doesn't that already break the while loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't break out of the while loop right away.

Everything in the loop runs before checking the condition again, so:

1. you check the condition
2. the dequeuing happens,
3. you check if we're at the goal,
4. you add all the children,
5. and then go back to (1) where you check the condition again.

So it briefly being empty in steps 2-4 doesn't matter as long as it's not empty any more when it gets back to step 1.

Comment: Thank you - I reviewed while loops and realized that aspect of while loops is what I needed to understand. Looks like checking the condition takes place when you go back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.
You first finish processing of the node ("`for each node n that is adjacent to current:`"...), during that you push neighbours of the node into the queue and then you check if the queue is empty.